# Wrap Images around images

Tags: html, css

Folks! I have been trying to solve this issue for a some time but no result. It is possible to wrap images around images with the help of css 'floats' or 'clears' or maybe another good way? See the screenshot, please - http://i27.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0204/41/540baedf99a08909593544ca4bb78241.png
Here is the link - http://layot.prestatrend.com/
Thanks!

Comment: I have done already but empty area is still there and not filled with image?

Comment: can you show your markup and css codes.It will help us to solve your problem.

Comment: http://layot.prestatrend.com - here is the link...

Comment: I think there is no way to do it with pure css...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have 3 Columns, these you can wrap into one DIV, float it left (or right, depending on the rest). 
This isn't just about images, it is generally about DOM-Elements. But i would say, the way to go is wrapping them into divs and formatting them that way.

Comment: It is not 3 columns it is one div with images floating: left... I do not understand if images have css float: left why empty area is still there not filled with image?

Comment: with float: XXX sometimes, if the image is only 1 px wider than the other one (or the browser thinks that way) then he is drawing the image to a new line. I would never place Images with their style alone, because they are sometimes a little bit difficult, place them into a div and you can force a specific width, hardcoded!

Answer (score 0):

You can either position the blocks manually (css positioning) or use something like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and let it position the blocks for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer, so the only one way is to use jQuery Mansonry or other script but no pure css way right?

Comment: It's the easiest way I would say. The disadvantage might be that you don't have the same level of control as when you do css positioning manually, but definitely time-saving. If there is no strict design specification saying this or that image should be exactly here and nowhere else, I would go for the jQuery Masonry. Just for the practical and future maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what your looking for, but you could try this:

```
#center_column .products_block ul li {
float: left;
margin-top: 0;
width: 234px !important;
margin-right: 1px;
margin-bottom: 1px;
padding: 0;
}
```

The style to note is: width: 234px !important;

When I added !important to the width attribute the gap between images went away. Hope this helps in some way.